# Why cannot asynchronous function inside ready() method be called in jquery version 2.2.4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, document-ready

I'm trying to nest some asynchronous works inside `ready` method but I'm getting stuck with jQuery version 2.2.4 (I prefer this version).

With jQuery version 2.2.4

```js
let initAsync = async function () {
  console.log('ready...'); // nothing will be logged
};

$(document).ready(initAsync);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

With jQuery 3.3.1

```js
let initAsync = async function () {
  console.log('ready...');
};

$(document).ready(initAsync);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Since the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) doesn't mention about this action, can you please explain me why?

Comment: `$(document).ready( function() { initAsync(); });` also working:  `$(document).ready(initAsync());`

Comment: @GrafiCode It's different.

Comment: From the link you posted: jQuery offers several ways to attach a function that will run when the DOM is ready. All of the following syntaxes are equivalent: `$(handler)` `$(document).ready(handler)` `$("document").ready(handle)` `$("img").ready(handler)` `$().ready(handler)`

Comment: https://blog.jquery.com/2016/07/07/jquery-3-1-0-released-no-more-silent-errors/ *While this was the right move for Deferreds, we had also changed jQuery.ready and jQuery.fn.ready to use the new spec-compliant Deferreds under the covers.*